# Parallel matrix multiplication in Python

Tags: python, matrix, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to do a matrix multiplication using multiple processes in python. My solution is slow and for matrices 2000*2000 its not working at all (it is stuck). Can someone please suggest me how to divide matrix to send it to processes? I am lost

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you're trying.

Comment: Do not write your own matrix multiplication in Python. First, because Python is not the good tool for that, but also because there are already many well-optimized libraries to do that existing since decades. The standard way is to use [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) libraries. These libraries are used by Python packages like Numpy, Tensorflow, etc. Some BLAS libraries are multithreaded (eg. OpenBLAS, BLIS, MKL) while some other implementations are sequential (eg. GSL, Netlib). Please use Numpy and check your installed BLAS implementation is parallel!

Comment: Thank you for the tips on the libraries. Although, sometimes, the goals is to see the multiplication running in the handmade way. In that cases, it is good to divide the matrix to submatrixes according to the number of processes you are using and each process is then working only on the submatrix provided. That is the solution I was looking for basically so I leave it here for future reference.